# Is Device.StartTime running in a seperate Thread or the UI Thread?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'd like to know when I use Device.StartTime, Will my code be executing in a separete thread or the UI Thread? Should I use InvokeOnMainThread()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, `Device.StartTime` run on the Main Thread so you don't need to call `InvokeOnMainThread` method.

Comment: This you can check in which Thread run.https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/85677/device-starttimer-does-it-run-on-main-thread